# xamarin inflate menu action bar icons not showing, only text appears

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

i use this code to create menu for action bar in xamarin. but text is being shown, not the icon. i want icons only to be appear. Here is what i try for creating the menu.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/action_reply"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_rotate"
    android:title="Reply"
    android:showAsAction="always" />
<item android:id="@+id/action_undo"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
    android:title="Undo"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Here is the action bar code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FEFEFE">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

can anyone suggest some improvements?

Comment: I am also getting this problem, always get the overflow icon and not the icons. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Same problem, any progress?

Comment: @Charl I found my solution with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25744146/action-bar-icon-not-showing-in-android-action-bar/25744230#25744230

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Android Support V7 Toolbar, you need to correct your menu to use `xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android-auto"` instead of `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android-auto"` then change `android:showAsAction="always"` to `local:showAsAction="always"`